# Wordpress - Buddypress messages - Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, buddypress

I've facing some issue and i cant resolve it yet.
I'm using [JWT-AUTH plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) for the authetincation and its working well.

I want to get the user's messages, but the api response return with 403 error code:

> Sorry, you cannot view the messages.

If I set the user to Administrator role, then I got 200 status code and got the messages.
The user's token include the user id ofc:

> "data": {
> "user": {
> "id": "2"
> }
> }

and this is my endpoint: /wp-json/buddypress/v1/messages?box=inbox&user_id=2

Can somebody help me with this?
Thank you!

I've tried to got the user's messages but i cant. Only if I set the user to administrator.

Answer (score 0):

An administrator has access to all the endpoints i.e. you are getting 200 responses when you try to access the messages as administrator.

If you want to access your own messages as other than the administrator, then you have to provide **thread Id** to the message endpoint.

```
https://your-site.com/wp-json/buddypress/v1/messages/{{thread_id}}?user_id={{your_user_id}}
```

Provide your **thread Id** from which messages you want to access and provide your **user Id**. Also, provide your authentication bearer token.

Click [here](https://developer.buddypress.org/bp-rest-api/reference/private-messaging/#retrieve-a-specific-messages-thread) for more information.